# using of GROUP BY with condition, how?

Tags: mysql, sql

I imagine how i can solve my task:

```
SELECT row, val1, val2, SUM(1) AS total
FROM mess
if(row < 0){ GROUP BY val1, val2 } if(row > 0) {GROUP BY val1}
```

I need to use two different GROUP BY in one SELECT, is it possable?

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT row, val1, val2, SUM(1) AS total, 
    CASE WHEN row<0 THEN val2 ELSE 0 END as group2
FROM mess
GROUP BY val1, group2
```

If row>0 all the values will be the same so group result will count val1 only

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT row, val1, val2, SUM(1) AS total
FROM mess
GROUP BY if(row>=0,val1,val1+','+val2)
```